# WSUS Alternatives

Tags: windows, wsus

I use SCE 2010 and find it a bit of a pig for updates.

Is there an easy to use alternative which can download updates to a central location and push them out? Or if not, automatically download them to the local machine (so some basic sofware to install updates locally).

My environment is Windows Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2008 R2, AD, etc. I have also seen the alternatives to WSUS thread but looking for anything else.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on why you think SCE is "a bit of a pig"; that really doesn't help us understand why it's not working for you, nor what solutions might work better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have a problem with SCE, but you haven't said why you have an issue with WSUS.

It's relatively lightweight, it's easily configurable and manageable, free with a Windows Server license, and it's the vendor-blessed way to control updates in your environment. What else could you possibly want? Personally, I don't really see a reason to use an alternative when the original is as easy as it is.

Comment: SCE and WSUS are two completely different products.

Comment: @GregD SCE uses WSUS for updates, it's partially integrated. SCCM does the same.

Comment: But in the context of SCE, WSUS isn't free and if the OP doesn't need all of the functionality of SCE, then it seems it's overkill.  SCE and WSUS are available as two separate products.

Answer (score 1):

[System Centers Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/system-center/essentials.aspx) could be a bit much if *all* you want to do is push **Microsoft** updates to servers and workstations.  However, there is so much more functionality you get from SCE besides just pushing updates, that I found it indispensable.

[Windows Server Update Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb332157) is it's lighter-weight brother.  Have you tried using just WSUS?

Comment: Hi, I still use SCE 2010 for monitoring and documenting the environment. I just find it quite confusing for updates. Anyway, WUInstsall